# Unable to access WD external drive

Tags: windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, freeze

Basically the HDD started acting weird (couldnt access files on it) and event viewer was flooded with "bad block" reports.

Now the HDD cant be accessed at all. It shows up in windows explorer when plugged in, but explorer hangs when i try to access it. Disk management hangs when i open it too.

Any idea what my options are here? I read that it may be an enclosure/interface issue, but that still doesnt help me get my data back without voiding the warranty. If i RMA it, i dont think they will let me transfer the data back...

Device manager just shows a exclamation mark next to "PCI device" under "other devices" but updating drivers doesnt help for that.

Comment: If you are getting bad blocks it sounds like the drive has failed mechanically.  You are right doing a warranty claim on the drive won't restore the data.  At this point your only option would be to remove it from the enclosure, so you MIGHT, be able to restore the data.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound stated, it seems the drive is failing on a hardware level.
Here are some ideas:

- Trying to get your data back yourself voiding the warranty

  - Open the enclosure and try connecting it directly to the computer using either an adapter or building it directly into a compatible computer. You may be able to access the data (or parts of it) if it was the external USB-Controller that failed.
  - If the drive itself is defect you are now stuck without data or warranty
  - You now have the optioin to spend about 999$ on professional data restoration
- Doing a warranty claim

  - Usually, warranty (if not specifically stated) does not include data recovery. Check if you bought special protection.
  - If not, go from your last backup and do a warranty claim
  - You now have a new HDD and your backed up data which in this situation is probably the best case scenario